# How feasible would a 24 hour "rolling" API endpoint be?

Tags: rest, google-cloud-functions

I've been victim of users using my undocumented API endpoints for quite a while now. But I've been thinking of an idea for the past few weeks, where the endpoint that my webapp uses, changes every 24-48 hours. This would be to discourage these users from reverse-engineering and using my API, subsequently using up my server resources.

How feasible would this be? And do you think there would be a way to automate this?

Comment: Why not have some sort of security in using your API?

Comment: You need to secure your endpoint(s). Consider using a standards based approach such as [oauth 2.0](https://oauth.net/2/)...